# Button above NSScrollView using autoLayout

Tags: cocoa, nsview, autolayout, nsscrollview

I have a Cocoa project using Autolayout, and I want to put a button (actually an `NSPathControl`) over a `NSScrollView` so that it stays in the same place on the screen even when the scrollView is scrolled.

Whenever I add the button to the scrollView's parent, it ends up behind the scrollView (even if I explicitly use `addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:`.  How do I get it to float above the scrollView?

My fallback is to put it inside of the scrollView, turn on `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and update the frame as the scrollView is scrolled. I would strongly prefer to use autolayout if possible though...

Edit: Here is the layout code for the button (the layout for content in the scrollView is quite complex):

```
NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
button.wantsLayer = YES;//Added incase this affects ordering (it doesn't seem to make a difference)
[self.superview addSubview:button positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:self];

[self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:20]];
[self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20]];
```

Comment: Can you add some of your auto layout code?

Comment: Added a code sample. It is in a NSScrollView subclass.

Comment: There is nothing in your constraints about the scrollView here? Do you have others as well?

Comment: self is a scrollView in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by setting wantsLayer to YES on the scrollView itself.